# Cual es codigo para instalar hrbrthemes

Tags: r, consola, instalacion

install.packages("hrbrthemes")
Error: unexpected string constant in:
"library(hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes)
install.packages(""
me aparece esto

Answer (score 0):

En el mismo [github de la librería](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes) aparecen varias opciones de descarga:

```
install.packages("hrbrthemes") # NOTE: CRAN version is 0.8.0
# or
install.packages("hrbrthemes", repos = c("https://cinc.rud.is", "https://cloud.r-project.org/"))
# or
remotes::install_git("https://git.rud.is/hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes.git")
# or
remotes::install_git("https://git.sr.ht/~hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes")
# or
remotes::install_gitlab("hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes")
# or
remotes::install_bitbucket("hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes")
# or
remotes::install_github("hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes")
```